# How to display two blog categories as separate sections on one page?

Tags: posts, categories

I have two blog categories that I want to display separately on the same page. In other words, one section will contain category 1 and the second section with contain category 2. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

To achieve this I would recommend using the [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class.

When using this approach, you are able to specify the parameters to search for posts (or categories) by.

For your particular question you should look at the [Category Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters). To target the categories you are looking for, you could do so by using their ID or their slug with the appropriate parameter label.

For example:

```
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array(
    'category_name'          => 'category-1',
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        // do something
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}
```

In the section where '// do something'' appears, is where you define what should be printed to the page.

There are useful websites you can use that generate this code for you - one such is [GenerateWP](https://generatewp.com/wp_query/).